# PhpStorm file template cursor position with spaces

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I want to create Live Template in PhpStorm. I pasted this code as a template.

```
ob_start();
var_dump( $END$ );
$imp_to_file = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('/var/www/Test/test.txt', $imp_to_file);
```

But when I try to reproduce this template in my code I got cursor in this position:

```
ob_start();
var_dump()[cursor here];
$imp_to_file = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('/var/www/Test/test.txt', $imp_to_file);
```

When I removed spaces around `$END$` and paste like this

```
ob_start();
var_dump($END$);
$imp_to_file = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('/var/www/Test/test.txt', $imp_to_file);
```

all works fine, but I need those spaces.

Please let me know what can I do here?

Comment: So .. is it Live Templates .. or File Templates actually? Please clarify that. If it's File Template -- how do you use it? It works fine for me if it's actual Live Template invocation (in .php file).

Comment: Post it as an Answer then -- may be useful for other users in similar situation (and questions with answers are easier to find/bigger change to be read)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I nailed it. It was just "reformat according to style" option.
Thanks all for your help.

[image]